# NPC version of player character attended the player's wedding?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So my brother completed Dawnguard DLC today, and because of a mod installed this allows him to marry Serana. He scheduled the wedding with Maramal, and waited inside the temple. When the wedding ended, we noticed someone very odd showed up. It was an NPC with the same name and physical appearance as him, but the size of a giant. They were wearing iron armor though, which the actual character is not, and all they did was congratulate him on the wedding. We even changed our name using the cheat room mod, and their's changed to reflect it. This play through is on modded Xbox 1 special edition, but it is not very heavy on the mods. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Please list your mods, and if you've tried disabling them to find out the offending mod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably caused by one of the mods you have installed. Try disabling your mods one by one to find out which mod introduces that NPC. @galacticninja hope you don't mind but you're right and i want to put it as an answer

Comment: I wrote that as a comment because it is not really an answer.

Comment: But I think it is